# How can I put the \caption{} right below the \includegraphics{} an align?

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, captions

I have been writing my paper in LaTex, but I can't put the `caption{}` right below the figure and align to it. I also need a single spacing from `\caption{}` to `\fonte{}`.

`\font{}` is from package `abntex2cite`.

formato.cls

```
\ProvidesClass{formato}
\LoadClass[12pt,openright,oneside,a4paper,article]{abntex2}

%%%%%%%% Packages
    \usepackage{newtxtext} %  font Times New Roman text
    %\usepackage{newtxmath} % font Times New Roman math
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
    \usepackage[brazil]{babel} 
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \RequirePackage[bibjustif, 
                    abnt-full-initials=yes, 
                    abnt-repeated-title-omit=yes, 
                    abnt-emphasize=it, 
                    alf]{abntex2cite} %  ABNT
    \usepackage{indentfirst} 
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage{amsmath} 
    \usepackage{calc}   
    \usepackage{xcolor} 
    \usepackage{graphicx} 
    \usepackage{float}    
    \usepackage{enumerate} 
    \usepackage{url}  
    \usepackage{setspace} 
    \usepackage{multirow} 
   \usepackage{caption} 

% Structure
\geometry{
 a4paper,
 left=2cm,
 right=2cm,
 top=2cm,
 bottom=2cm
 }
\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.2cm}  
\DoubleSpacing        


\captionsetup[table]{
  justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false,
  labelsep=colon
  }
\captionsetup[figure]{
  justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false,
  labelsep=colon
  }

\makeindex
```

main.tex

```
\documentclass{formato}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Distribuição do ROA do exercício}
  \label{fig:freqsobras}
  \fonte{Elaborado pelo autor.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

What I have:

[image]

What I need:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "align" and "simple spacement"?

Comment: Align to the image and single spacing*. I edited my post.

Comment: I don't know how to do it off-hand, but you're wanting to "left-align" the caption.

Comment: @Teepeemm thanks, i did with `\captionsetup{justification=raggedright, singlelinecheck=false}` from `caption` package. Now I need to do a single spacing.

Comment: single spacing is the default in latex, you have provided no code to show double spacing and your caption only has one line so it is hard to see what change you want. The `\fonte` command you show is non standard and you give no definition for it so we can not comment on the space between `\caption` and `\fonte`.

Comment: please always give a _complete_ small document that shows your problem, you can use `example-image` for the example as that is available for tests. Then people can reproduce the issue and debug.

Comment: If you mean to add a single space between the caption and the left margin, you can also specify the width or margin (see page 12 of caption manual).

Comment: off-topic: `align` refers to a specific math display structure.  I've changed the tag to "horizontal alignment".